# Changing the column width of the jtable

Tags: java, swing

Am trying to change the column widith of the column a jtable but when i compile the code,the widith remains the same.

```
            jTable2.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        jTable2.setForeground(Color.BLACK);
       jTable2.setShowHorizontalLines(true);
       jTable2.setShowVerticalLines(true);
     jTable2.setRowHeight(50);
      jTable2.getTableHeader().getBackground().brighter();
     jTable2.getTableHeader().setBackground(Color.RED);
       jTable2.getTableHeader().setForeground(Color.blue);
    column1=  new ArrayList<> ();

     column1.add("Transaction Id");
     column1.add("Transaction Date");
     column1.add("Narration");
     column1.add("Value Date");
     column1.add("Debit Amount");
     column1.add("Credit Amount");
     column1.add("Ledger Balance");
     column1.add("Credit Account No.");
     column1.add("Credit Account Name");
     column1.add("Transaction Ref No.");
     column1.add("Cheque No.");
     column1.add("Transaction Type");
     column1.add("Staff ID");
     column1.add("Transaction Time");
     **for (int i = 0; i < jTable2.getModel().getColumnCount(); i++) {

   if (i == 2) {

   column=jTable2.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
   column.setPreferredWidth(200);

   } else {
   column.setPreferredWidth(50);
   }}** 

    JDBCConnectionPigs csx = new JDBCConnectionPigs();
                    Connection csx1 = csx.createConnection();
   try {
   csx1.setAutoCommit(false); 
    PreparedStatement ps1 = csx1.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM            bsanca01100000310");
    ResultSet rst=ps1.executeQuery();

    data5= new ArrayList<>();
    int i=0;
    while (rst.next())

   {
  data4= new ArrayList<> ();
 data4.add(0, rst.getInt("trn_id")+"");
   data4.add(1, rst.getDate("trn_date")+"");     
   data4.add(2, rst.getString("narration"));         
    data4.add(3, rst.getDate("value_date")+""); 
     data4.add(4, rst.getString("debit")); 
      data4.add(5, rst.getString("credit"));
      data4.add(6, rst.getString("ledger_balance"));
      data4.add(7, rst.getString("credit_account_no"));
      data4.add(8, rst.getString("credit_account_name"));
      data4.add(9, rst.getString("tra_ref_number"));
       data4.add(10, rst.getString("chq_number"));
       data4.add(11, rst.getString("trn_type"));
      data4.add(12, rst.getString("staff_id"));
        data4.add(13, rst.getTime("trn_time")+"");
           data5.add(i, data4);
         i++;
         }
       model= new    MyTableModel(data5,column1);  
        jTable2.setModel(model);

          csx1.setAutoCommit(true);
           }                                        
         catch (SQLException ex) {

               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.toString());

             }
```

can any one help me to identify where where the problem is or a better way to implement this. Sorry for the bather because the question seam trivial but it has given me hard time.

Comment: You seem to be changing only the maximum width of column 2, not its preferred width.

Comment: @RealSkeptic, i have changed the property to prefferedWidth but nothing changes:

Comment: @Googo, post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem. The custom TableModel is not relevant to the problem and should not be included in the SSCCE. That is, first learn how to set the column widths using a JTable with the DefaultTableModel.

Comment: @camickr, ok, ignoring the table model, what could be the problem. because i actually thought that because the table implements an abstract table model may not allow adjustments through defaultablemodel.

Comment: @Googo, The width of the column is related to the View (ie. the JTable) not the TableModel (which just stores the data). I don't know what the problem is because your code is wrong and you haven't posted the code demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @camickr, i have posted the code where am trying to change the width, could there be any thing that am not doing properly?

Comment: @Googo, That is NOT a SSCCE. I already told you the TableModel (and its data) is irrelevant to the problem. The code does not compile so how are we supposed to test the code???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jTable2.setModel(model);
```

The above statement is the problem. When you change the `TableModel` of the table, the `TableColumnModel` is recreated so you lose all the custom column widths.

You need to reset the column width AFTER you change the model.